# Div Overflow on mouse out of div

Tags: html, css

I have a `<div>` which I set to:

```
height: 200px;
overflow: auto;
```

If I point my mouse inside the `<div>` and scroll up and down, when my mouse leaves the `<div>`, I need to click outside the `<div>` to get back my scroll control.

How do I change or add code to make it that on my mouse move out of the `<div>`, I will gain back the scroll control to the main scroll bar and does not have to click anywhere else.

Comment: You must show your approach to the problem . show your code that you tried.

Comment: @Nazim actually what I did is just add this 2 value. and move my mouse inside the div with scroll.

Comment: On what you are applying the style? Your tags say you are on using jQuery? Please make a Fiddle and show the behavior you are trying to descripe.
*At this point your question have too few informations. No one will be able to understand what you are doing.*

Comment: @termnml its just a normal html

Comment: @Max this way no one can help you. So its an empty div just in the body with no text or filler? Then there is nothing to scroll. Unable to understand you. -> jsfiddle.net

Comment: @termnml http://jsfiddle.net/uax7hcg3/1/ Thanks!

Comment: For me it works OK, but it can depend on browser which you are using, did you checked it with other browsers?

Comment: @Max Okay there is no JS capturing anything by the mouse.
This behavior is system dependent. Are you on windows? Mac? Linux?
Which browser? And as jazzgot mentioned, just check with othe browsers. **This behavior has nothing to do with your HTML nor CSS Code.**